# Duplicate detection of customers

Tags: machine-learning, duplicates

What are the current algorithms that exist for detecting duplicate accounts by the same costumer?
This would be for customers who are trying to hide the fact that they opened two different accounts. For example, maybe they changed their name to a shorter version or used another email account in their second account.

What kind of algorithm is used for that? Not sure if something like MinHashing is a good idea here.

Comment: It is not like MinHashing will magically solve your problem -- easiest way to detect "same" customer is by IP/email but you still need to chose particular features that will be hashed, but there is not enough info to recommend something. There ARE sophisticated algorithms that allow you to find similarities in behaviour, but I doubt this are the ones you need.

Comment: And talking about sophisticated algorithms, a lot of research was done in field of MMO games, [just as an example, this paper](http://eldar.mathstat.uoguelph.ca/dashlock/CIG2013/papers/paper_29.pdf)

Comment: Thanks guys. You gave me some ideas